# Tkinter entry field and loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops, search, tkinter

I'am trying to make a simple module for payments and understand python better via trying to work on a small project/script. Here is my code for one of my modules:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
t1=IntVar()
t2=StringVar()
t3=IntVar()
t4=IntVar()
t5=IntVar()
t6=IntVar()

def verify():
     with open('dbase.txt') as x:
         input1 = t1.get()
         code=[input1]
         for n, line in enumerate(x, 1):
              split_line = line.split()
              for i in code:
                   if i in split_line:
                        item=n+1
                        sale_price=n+2
                        purchase_price=n+3
                        u=x.readline(item)
                        w=x.readline(sale_price)
                        v=x.readline(purchase_price)
                        t2.set(u)
                        t3.set(int(w))
                        t4.set(int(v))

def saved():
     change=int(t5.get())-int(t3.get())
     t6.set(change)

l1=Label(root, text='Code').grid(column=0, row=0)
e1=Entry(root, text=t1).grid(column=1, row=0)
b1=Button(root, text='Verify', command=verify).grid(column=1, row=1)
l2=Label(root, text='Item').grid(column=0, row=2)
e2=Entry(root, text=t2).grid(column=1, row=2)
l3=Label(root, text='Sale Price').grid(column=0, row=3)
e3=Entry(root, text=t3).grid(column=1, row=3)
l4=Label(root, text='Purchase Price').grid(column=0, row=4)
e4=Entry(root, text=t4).grid(column=1, row=4)
l5=Label(root, text='Amount Paid').grid(column=0, row=5)
e5=Entry(root, text=t5).grid(column=1, row=5)
b1=Button(root, text='Save', command=saved).grid(column=1, row=6)
l5=Label(root, text='Change').grid(column=0, row=7)
e5=Entry(root, text=t6).grid(column=1, row=7)
```

Here is the .txt file from which the code is reading from:

```
1001
sugar
20
30
```

The GUI with tkinter has some entry fields. The challenge is that once the commands on the buttons are passed, the IntVar() t2, t3,t4 and t6  cannot be set to show the amount. Where is the code wrong and what are better ways of handling this?

Comment: The optional parameter to `.readline()` is a maximum number of characters to read - you seem to be expecting it to be a line number.

Comment: Help me understand. my view is that the 'n' in line of code: for n, line in enumerate(x, 1): ,the line split, and the line positions of (n+1, n+2)...) are all meant to locate certain positions of lines in x. Therefore, when i write .readline(line_position), doesn't it now returns a list of items or numbers in that selected line_position?

Comment: The position `.readline()` starts from is always the position the previous read ended (or otherwise set by `.seek()`).  The only thing you can do with the parameter is limit the line length, possibly resulting in a partial line being read.  If you want to access lines by number, the simplest way is to read the entire file once with `.readlines()` (note the 's'), then index into the list that returned.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Harper pointed out in the comments you probably want to do something with `readlines()` instead of `readline`.

That said I noticed you were assigning the `IntVar`'s and `StringVar` to the entry fields using `text`. This works on entry fields because they only have a `textvariable` option and not a `text` option so it is accepting this arguement in place of `textvariable` but no other method that accepts text will work with these kinds of variables. So you should keep that in mind.

One way to manage everything is to place all your `IntVar`'s and `StringVar` into a list. By doing this we can use a simple `for index,` code to append the data to each variable.

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

my_vars = [IntVar(), StringVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()]

def verify():
    with open('dbase.txt') as x:
        input1 = x.readlines()
        print(input1)
        for ndex, i in enumerate(input1):
            my_vars[ndex].set(i)

def saved():
    change=int(my_vars[4].get())-int(my_vars[2].get())
    my_vars[5].set(change)

l1=Label(root, text='Code').grid(column=0, row=0)
e1=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[0]).grid(column=1, row=0)
b1=Button(root, text='Verify', command=verify).grid(column=1, row=1)
l2=Label(root, text='Item').grid(column=0, row=2)
e2=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[1]).grid(column=1, row=2)
l3=Label(root, text='Sale Price').grid(column=0, row=3)
e3=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[2]).grid(column=1, row=3)
l4=Label(root, text='Purchase Price').grid(column=0, row=4)
e4=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[3]).grid(column=1, row=4)
l5=Label(root, text='Amount Paid').grid(column=0, row=5)
e5=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[4]).grid(column=1, row=5)
b1=Button(root, text='Save', command=saved).grid(column=1, row=6)
l5=Label(root, text='Change').grid(column=0, row=7)
e6=Entry(root, textvariable=my_vars[5]).grid(column=1, row=7)

root.mainloop()
```

Before:

[image]

After pressing verify:

[image]

Comment: This code was very helpful. Among you with experience in Python, is there a way in which code can be designed to 'pass' entries in the entry boxes by automatically searching for '1001' in the .txt document after its entered at code entry and displaying it in the respective fields? I mean, right now, only after the command at 'Verify' is executed can it display. Can it display automatically without pressing button?

Comment: Sure you can tell the program to search by calling the function after all your fields are created. So at the bottom just above the mainloop write `verify()`.